# Antivirus for power users

Tags: anti-virus

All antivirus software I've come across (so far)

- has an installer;
- runs in the background (usually via drivers);
- uses up a lot of CPU and/or RAM bandwidth;
- very rarely finds any virus (as viruses are pretty uncommon these days).

I'd like a very simple antivirus:

- no installer (.7z is fine);
- no drivers, only one application, only runs in the foreground;
- only scans what I tell it to scan (i.e. .exe files I downloaded and such).

Is there such a thing? Or anything close? (If you make it, I and the rest of the superuser community will buy it!)

Comment: @Ramhound: Of course it's Windows. I'm not looking for rootkit extermination, I just want to verify binaries I download before I run them. Antivirus without drivers may be useless to you; I can only assume you didn't read the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [ClamWin](http://www.clamwin.com/content/view/118/89/). You can create a portable setup as well.

I believe it meets all of your requirements.

Comment: I'd have said ClamAV, since technically he didn't say platform. I run it on my mac and used to on my XP box before I retired it

Comment: That's true. I figured it was Windows since there aren't too many linux av programs that are as robust as what he was running into.

Comment: Awesome, excellent, wonderful! Better than I'd imagined!